# QA automación Python error al Abrir ventana

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Espero que anden bien quería hacer una pregunta...
recientemente me dio este error cuando intenten automatizar un browser..

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49640/devtools/browser/217d9ac5-2f6f-4d3f-bf7a-f423203257fa
EC:\Users\foviedo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\unittest\case.py:621: ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=316, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 49635), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 49623)>
  outcome.errors.clear()
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

======================================================================
ERROR: test_probando (__main__.TestWeb)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\foviedo\Desktop\QAAutomation\Pista1.py", line 8, in setUp
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe")
  File "C:\Users\foviedo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\foviedo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\foviedo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\foviedo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\foviedo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 94
Current browser version is 93.0.4577.82 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.